# Pre Select interest Groups Mailchimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp to add a subscribe form on the site, 
I have added interest groups, all checkboxes, 
They are almost 40,

I need to show the form in a popup on my site, upon click, and i have used jquery Modal for it.

The issue is that i want to display all the checkboxes of the interest groups  as checked by default when the form loads, how can i do that ?

I am currently using the form url Mailchimp provides me in an iframe included in the modal box body.

Currently i use embedded form and check all the checkboxes manually, but upon submit, it redirects me to another tab, it should remain in the same modal box

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this isn't possible with the iFrame modal. It's not a feature MailChimp offers and browser security will not allow Javascript from your site to interact with the HTML in the iFrame.

In order to implement this feature, you'll need to write your own form.